# How do I bulk/chunk paginate existing Seq[(String)] session value in Gatling?

Tags: gatling

I am executing a call that saves a lot of values into a Seq[(String)], it looks as follows:

```
.exec(session => {session.set("Ids", session("externalIds").as[Seq[String]])})
```

There is a reason why I have to create another session variable called Ids our of externalIds but I wont get into it now.

I than have to execute another call and paginate 10 values out of ${Ids} until I send them all.
(So in case of 100 values, I'll have to execute this call 10 times)
The JSON looks as follows:

```
..."Ids": [
    "962950",
    "962955",
    "962959",
    "962966",
    "962971",
    "962974",
    "962978",
    "962983",
    "962988",
    "962991"
],...
```

What I usually do when I have to iterate through one value each time is simply:

```
  .foreach("${Ids}", "id") {
              exec(getSomething)
          }
```

But since I need to send a [...] Of 10 values each, I am not sure if it should even be in the scenario level. Help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to go about this within the session so I took it
outside to a function and here is the solution:

```
 .exec(session => {session.set("idSeqList", convertFileIdSeqToFileIdSeqList(session("idsSeq").as[Seq[String]]))})

 def convertFileIdSeqToFileIdSeqList(idSeq: Seq[String]): Seq[Seq[String]] = {
    idSeq.grouped(10).toList
  }
```

Note that when placing your list within a JSON body, you will need to use .jsonStringify() to format it correctly in the JSON context like so:

```
  "ids": ${ids.jsonStringify()},
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [transform](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-check-transform) in your check to transform your Seq[String] into chunks, eg with [Seq#grouped](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! transform seems to work only on check, however "ids" is being collected on multiple requests (I am actually paginating a request that collects it). This means that I have to find a way to execute grouped on an existing session value.